# Want to make cell of 1 row of angular ui grid columndef editable

Tags: css, angular-ui, ui-grid

how to change columndef settings dynamically loaded , like one row must be editable and other should not be editable when loaded,but mine whenever celleditable true for one row it makes all other rows cells also editable

Comment: What did you try? Pleas see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi,I wanted to know how to make a cell in a row editable in angular ui grid having coldef loaded dynamically

Comment: This is not a forum webpage, but a Q&A one. So, if you can, please update the question itself.

Comment: angular.forEach($scope.gridApi.grid.renderContainers.body.visibleColumnCache, function (item, i) {
                        item.cellClass = function getCellClassEdit(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
                            if (row.entity.$$treeLevel == 0) {
                           
                                var t = grid.getCellValue(row, col).toLowerCase();

Comment: above not working for each item in a columndef ,i want a property of a column to  change before rows are rendered

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand if you meant 1 row or row 1. But customizing the celltemplates of columns based on rowRenderIndex might help.

```
var gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        rowTemplate: rowTemplate(),
        data: [{one : 1, two : 2, three: 3, four : 4, five:5 }],
        columnDefs: [
          { field: 'one' },
          { field: 'two' },
          { field: 'three' },
          { field: 'four' },
          { field: 'five', cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
          <input ng-if="!rowRenderIndex" type=number />
          <span ng-if="rowRenderIndex">{{row.entity.five}}</span>
          </div>'}
        ]
      };
```